# How do I access index from filter in java?

Tags: java, list

I'm planning to convert the following without a for loop and using functional programming:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Feedback: avoid for and mutation
  if (target.charAt(i) == letter && target.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(i)) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

How do I achieve the if condition with the indexes with the filter?

Comment: Can you provide some context as to what this code is doing?  Like what are the functional requirements for this?

Comment: Try and describe what problem this code solves. It may be easier to reason about it in a functional way if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [IntStream.range()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) for this case

```
int count = (int) IntStream.range(0, 5)
        .filter(i -> target.charAt(i) == letter && target.charAt(i) == answer.charAt(i))
        .count();
```

Comment: This code will fail to compile because the return type of `count()` is `long`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a Wordle related problem, based on the words both having five letters. If you are open to using a third-party library, the following code will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
@Test
public void zipChar()
{
    char letter = 'o';
    CharAdapter target = Strings.asChars("tools");
    CharAdapter guess = Strings.asChars("boots");

    int count = target.zipChar(guess)
        .count(pair -> pair.getOne() == pair.getTwo() && pair.getOne() == letter);

    Assertions.assertEquals(2, count);
}
```

The code zips two Strings together and uses the `count` method which takes a `Predicate`. Since the Strings are zipped together into `CharCharPair` instances, there is no need to use indexes or `filter` here.

There is a [Java 17 Wordle Checker tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5--tDQIMqhY&t=1214s) from José Paumard on the Java YouTube channel that you might find helpful.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are want to find out how many given characters (denoted as `letter`  in your code) there are in two strings `target` and `guess` at the *same positions* in both.

Firstly you shouldn't hard-code `i < 5` conditions like that. I doubt that you intended to create a method that is able to process only *strings* with a length of precisely **5** characters. Strings of length 3 or 8 would require another method? Also `target` and `guess` could be of different lengths.

Keeping all that in mind this condition from your loop boils down to:

```
    `i < Math.min(target.length(), guess.length())`.
```

To implement this task using Stream IPA you might mimic your for loop with a help of [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#method-summary).

Its method `range()`, which actually utilizes **for loop** under the hood, except two arguments: *starting index* and *end index* (exclusive). So arguments passed to the `range()` are basically the same as you might use in a for loop.

`filter()` expects an instance of [**Predicate**](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-predicate-examples/) which is a **functional interface** build-in in JDK, and represents *boolean condition*.

Method `count()` is a **terminal operation** that returns a *number of elements* in the stream (*after applying all preceding operations that reduce the number of elements*) as a `long`.

The code might look like this:

```
    long count = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(target.length(), guess.length()))
                .filter(i -> target.charAt(i) == letter && 
                             target.charAt(i) == guess.charAt(i))
                .count();
```